# Splitting list of objects by DateTime property

Tags: c#, .net, datetime, split, asp.net-mvc-5

I'm building a booking system for cinemas(of course it's just small project for studies).

Here is my **Showcase model**:

```
public class ShowcaseModel
{
    public string objectId { get; set; }
    public string MovieId { get; set; }
    public int Auditorium { get; set; }

    public DateTime? StartDate { get; set; }
}
```

I want to display schedule in `"per day"` form. To achieve this i get all Showcases where DateTime is greater than today and put them into

```
List< ShowcaseModel >.
```

Now i don't know how to split this list(into separate lists) by day using StartDate property.

Is there any way to achieve this?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [GroupBy](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb534501(v=vs.110).aspx) method:

```
List<ShowcaseModel> list = new List<ShowcaseModel>();
//...
var gooupByDay = list.GroupBy(o=>o.StartDate.Value.Date);
```

Answer (score 1):

I have used fixture (simply creates random instances of your class) to demonstrate how you can get a list of items per date.

```
var fixture = new Fixture();

IEnumerable<ShowcaseModel> showCaseModel = fixture.CreateMany<ShowcaseModel>();
IEnumerable<ShowcaseModel> futureShowCases = showCaseModel.Where(s => s.StartDate != null && s.StartDate > DateTime.Now);

// we know none of start dates are null
var groupedShowCases = futureShowCases.GroupBy(s => s.StartDate.Value.Date);

List<Tuple<DateTime, IEnumerable<ShowcaseModel>>> showCasesByDate = new List<Tuple<DateTime, IEnumerable<ShowcaseModel>>>();
foreach (var groupedShowCase in groupedShowCases)
{
    var key = groupedShowCase.Key;
    showCasesByDate.Add(Tuple.Create(key, groupedShowCase.ToList().AsEnumerable()));
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Using Linq `GroupBy()`

```
var grouped = list.Where(f=>f.StartDate!= null)
            .GroupBy(f => f.StartDate.Value.Date, b => b,
                               (k, g) => new { Date= k.Date, 
                                               Movies= g }).ToList();
```

Assuming `list` is a collection of your ShowCaseModel