# Get Total of a field in mvc entitymodel 1st

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I am trying to get total on my view.
I am confused what should i do? Please help me out..
I am not understanding where should i use query and ofc I need it in my view to show but how?

### Model class

```
    namespace BOL1
{
  public  class ADetailsVm
    {
        public List<BOL1.tbl_Transiction> Payables { get; set; }
        public List<BOL1.tbl_Transiction> Reciveables { get; set; }
    }
}
```

DbContext

```
    public partial class bankingEntities : DbContext
    {
        public bankingEntities()
            : base("name=bankingEntities")
        {
        }

        protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
        {
            throw new UnintentionalCodeFirstException();
        }

        public virtual DbSet<tbl_Accounts> tbl_Accounts { get; set; }
        public virtual DbSet<tbl_Transiction> tbl_Transiction { get; set; }
        public virtual DbSet<tbl_TransictionType> tbl_TransictionType { get; set; }
        public DbSet<ADetailsVm> ADetailsVm { get; set; }
    }
}
```

### Controller

```
 public class Details : Controller
    {

        private TransictionBs objbs;
        public Details() 
        {
            objbs = new TransictionBs();
        }
        // GET: Shinwari/AccountDetails
        [HttpGet]
        public ActionResult Index(int accountid)
        {
            ADetailsVm v = new ADetailsVm();
            //Load both the collection properties
            v.Payables = objbs.GetALL().Where(p => p.AId == accountid && p.tbl_TransictionType.Type.Contains("Payable")).ToList();
            v.Reciveables = objbs.GetALL().Where(r => r.AId==accountid && r.tbl_TransictionType.Type.Contains("Reciveable")).ToList();

            return View(v);
```

### View

```
@model BOL1.ADetailsVm
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Index";
}

<h2>AccountDetails</h2>

<p>
    @Html.ActionLink("Create New", "Create")
</p>
<table id="Payables" class="table">
    <tr>
        <th>
            Date
        </th>
        <th>
            Discription
        </th>
        <th>
            Amount
        </th>
    </tr>

    @foreach (var item in Model.Payables)
    {
        <tr>
            <td>
                @item.Date
            </td>
            <td>
                @item.TDiscription
            </td>
            <td>
                @item.Amount
            </td>
        </tr>
    }

</table>
```

Comment: TOTAL of Amount shown in  current table

Comment: Can i chose total Amount by month ?

Comment: You need to do a GroupBy on your data. Ask a new question with relevant code needed.

Comment: I cant post more questions due to my reputation

Comment: Take a look at [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/34407775/40521) answer. That might help you to get started.

Comment: yeah i get it but what if i want to select month and year by dropdown and then show records for selected month year

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the LINQ `Sum` extension method on the `Amount` property(*assuming it is of numeric type*) of your `Payables` collection property of the view model.

```
<h2> @Model.Payables.Sum(s=>s.Amount) </h2>
```

Or if you do not like adding so much C# code in razor views(*like me :*)), You may add a new property to store the total in your view model.

```
public  class ADetailsVm
{
    public decimal TotalPayableAmount { set;get;}
    public List<BOL1.tbl_Transiction> Payables { get; set; }
    public List<BOL1.tbl_Transiction> Reciveables { get; set; }
}
```

and in your action method, call the `Sum` method and set the value to our new `TotalPayableAmount`  property.

```
public ActionResult Index(int accountid)
{
    var v = new ADetailsVm();

    v.Payables = objbs.GetALL().Where(p => p.AId == accountid &&
                               p.tbl_TransictionType.Type.Contains("Payable")).ToList();
    v.Reciveables = objbs.GetALL().Where(r => r.AId == accountid && 
                            r.tbl_TransictionType.Type.Contains("Reciveable")).ToList();

    v.TotalPayableAmount=  v.Payables.Sum(s=>s.Amount)

    return View(v);
}
```

and in your view

```
@model ADetailsVm
<h2>@Model.TotalPayableAmount</h2>
```